# How can I encrypt a file?

Tags: files, encryption

I would like to download some files from my server into my laptop, and the thing is that I want this communication to be as stealth and secure as it can be. So, far I came up using VPN, in that way I redirect the whole internet traffic of my laptop via my server. Additionally, I tried to send a file using ftp and observing Wireshark at the same time. The communication seems to be encrypted, however I would like also to encrypt the file itself (as a 2nd step security or something like that).

My server is a RasPi running Raspbian.
My laptop is Macbook Air.

I want firstly to encrypt a file in my Ras Pi and secondly download it. How can I do that?

Comment: `gpg` can encrypt files, either asymmetrically (using a public key for encryption and a private key for decryption) or symmetrically (using the same key/password for encryption and decryption: http://www.dewinter.com/gnupg_howto/english/GPGMiniHowto.html

Comment: Why not use a protocol such as HTTPS, SFTP or FTPS? If the communication is encrypted, adding a second layer of encryption won't gain you anything.

Comment: Encryption at rest is standard required security practice for sensitive files such as medical or financial data. It protects data not actively in use against file system compromise.

Comment: Please stop using FTP. Yes, using a point-to-point vpn compensates for most of FTPs faults, but there are lots of better solutions. The world has moved on. So should you.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use `openssl` to encrypt and decrypt using key based symmetric ciphers.  For example:

```
openssl enc -in foo.bar \
    -aes-256-cbc \
    -pass stdin > foo.bar.enc
```

This encrypts `foo.bar` to `foo.bar.enc` (you can use the `-out` switch to specify the output file, instead of redirecting stdout as above) using a 256 bit [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) cipher in [CBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29) mode.  There are various other ciphers available (see `man enc`).  The command will then wait for you to enter a password and use that to generate an appropriate key.  You can see the key with `-p` or use your own in place of a password with `-K` (actually it is slightly more complicated than that since an [initialization vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) or source is needed, see `man enc` again).  If you use a password, you can use the same password to decrypt, you do not need to look at or keep the generated key.

To decrypt this:

```
openssl enc -in foo.bar.enc \
    -d -aes-256-cbc \
    -pass stdin > foo.bar
```

Notice the `-d`.  See also `man openssl`.

Comment: Also, you can output the result to a file using the option `-out FILENAME` rather than piping in the output.

Comment: nowadays (`openssl 1.1.1l` on Ubuntu), it seems that: 1. it is a good idea to add `-pbkdf2` and 2. it is better to leave out `-pass stdin`: with `-pass stdin`, on my system the passphrase is shown in plain text; without it, `openssl` asks "enter aes-256-cbc encryption password:", which then can be entered without showing up.

Answer (score 8):

For one-off cases you can encrypt using zip and a password.  While not as strong as key based techniques (because it is hard to have a good password) it is probably fine ad-hoc situations.

Command line looks like this:

```
zip -r -0 -e encrypted_file.zip /path/to/files

-r to recurse directories.
-e to encrypt
```

Comment: to open the file: `unzip encrypted_file.zip`

Answer (score 5):

Slight mods to @goldilocks answer:

**Encryption**

```bsh
openssl enc -in foo -aes-256-cbc -pbkdf2 -out foo.enc
```

Differences:

1. By leaving out the `-pass stdin` args, this will prompt "enter aes-256-cbc encryption password:" and let you type the passphrase without showing in your console;
2. It will use the `PBKDF2` algorithm with default iterations, and suppress the warning "*** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used. Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better."

**Decryption**

```bsh
openssl enc -d -in foo.enc -aes-256-cbc -pbkdf2 -out foo.plain
```